# How to post Imageview image to server?

Tags: android

I have an imageview where I am setting image and on click that image send to server. How I can do it?

Comment: http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/android-image-upload-activity/

Comment: The key to asking questions on SO, is to ask questions that can't easily be answered by Google. Search of 'android send image to server' resulted in: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=33-mJVQ5Ui7ScDQdBFkBOg&cp=18&gs_id=1y&xhr=t&q=android+send+image+to+server&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=android+send+image&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=95c2cca83de3aed3&biw=1680&bih=912. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Add library ٰVolley

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

and Permission net in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Take a photo of the imageview and convert it to the string

```
  ImageView   ivImage1 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.img_add1_send );

  String mmm=getStringImage( ( ( BitmapDrawable ) ivImage1.getDrawable( ) ).getBitmap( ) );
```

Functional conversion of a photo into a string

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bm){
    ByteArrayOutputStream ba=new ByteArrayOutputStream(  );
    bm.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,ba );
    byte[] by=ba.toByteArray();
    String encod= Base64.encodeToString( by,Base64.DEFAULT );
    return encod;
}
```

And converted the string into JSON

```
JSONObject requestJsonObject = new JSONObject( );
requestJsonObject.put( "image", mmm );
```

We send JSON to the server with the following function

```
        JsonObjectRequest jjj = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST,
            "http://192.168.16.1/dashbDoard/wDaryounes/GetDShopDDDBojId.php", requestJsonObject,
            new Response.Listener< JSONObject >( ) {
                @Override
                public void onResponse( JSONObject response ) {

                    if ( response == 1 ) {
                        
                
                        Toast.makeText( getApplication(), "yessss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show( );
                    } else {
                        
                            Toast.makeText( getApplication(), "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show( );

                        }
                    },new Response.ErrorListener( ) {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse( VolleyError error ) {

                        }
                    } );
                    jjj.setRetryPolicy( new DefaultRetryPolicy( 18000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT ) );
                    Volley.newRequestQueue( G.context ).add( jjj );


            }
```

On the server, it's easy to turn this string into a photo

code php

```
$image = $_POST['image'];

$decodedImage = base64_decode($image);

$location = "img/" . $title . "_" . rand(rand(5, 50), rand(500, 900)) .
            "_" . date("i") . "_" . date("d-m-Y") . ".jpg";

$resultOfCreatingImage = file_put_contents($location, $decodedImage);

if ($resultOfCreatingImage == false) {
    $error['error'] = "failure_creating_image";
} else {
    $q = "INSERT INTO ads( image) VALUES(?)";
    $res = $connect->prepare($q);
    $res->execute([$location]);
    if ($res->rowCount() > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```